# In what scenario is exponential function not true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exponential-function

if $x>0$ for $x^a=x^b$ then what conclusion can be made with $a$ and $b$ ?

My solution:

Step 1. $x^a=x^b$

Step 2. $e^{a\cdot \ln x}=e^{b\cdot \ln x}$

Step 3. $a\ln x=b\ln x$

Step 4. $a=b$

My answer would be that you can conclude that $a=b$, however this is wrong in the solutions. The solution says that no conclution can be made. In what scenario is $a\ne b$ ? And why is my answer wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: the issue is between step 3 and step 4 :)

Comment: $1^2=1^3$. $\quad$

Comment: Take x=1 for example. (No dividing by 0! Where did you divide?)

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got it! No dividing with ln(x)!